# iOS - Text not looking good with OpenGL

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing text with OpenGL ES 2.0, but the result doesn't look good (especially the bottom of "t"):

[image]

(It looks kinda pixelized and blurred)

I don't know exactly why since I load the font in high res (200px or 400px) for example.

I draw each char in an image, that compose the texture atlas. So all the chars can be displayed at any time without loading. I scale the texture with openGL (MVP matrix), but it shouldn't look as bad anyway.

Here's an UIImage of the char "t" that I retrieve with the method below, before it's processed with openGL :

[image]

(You can see it look way better without OpenGL)

Here's the code I use to create an image from a char :

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string dimensions:(CGSize)dimensions alignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment fontName:(NSString *)name fontSize:(CGFloat)size {
    NSUInteger width, height, i;
    CGContextRef context;
    void *data;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    UIFont *font;

    font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:size];
    width = (NSUInteger)dimensions.width;
    height = (NSUInteger)dimensions.height;

    while(dimensions.width > kMaxTextureSize && size > 0) {
        font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size: --size];
        dimensions = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
        width = (GLuint)NextPowerOfTwo((int)dimensions.width);
        height = (GLuint)NextPowerOfTwo((int)dimensions.height);
    }

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    data = calloc(1, width * height * 4);

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data,
            width, height,
            8,
            4 * width,
            colorSpace,
            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f); //NOTE: NSString draws in UIKit referential i.e. renders upside-down compared to CGBitmapContext referential
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = @{
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: @1.0F,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: whiteColor
    };

    CGRect destRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, YES);

    [string drawInRect:destRect
        withAttributes:attrsDictionary];

    CGImageRef cgImageFinal = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    self = [self initWithData:data pixelFormat:GL_RGBA
                   pixelsWide:width pixelsHigh:height];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(data);

    return self;
}
```

And here's the code to retrieve a openGL texture from it :

```
- (id)initWithData:(const void *)data
       pixelFormat:(GLenum)pixelFormat
        pixelsWide:(NSUInteger)width
        pixelsHigh:(NSUInteger)height {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        switch (pixelFormat) {
            case GL_RGBA:
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                break;
            case GL_RGB:
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, data);
                break;
            case GL_ALPHA:
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, width, height, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                break;
            default:
                [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@""];
        }

        self.width = width;
        self.height = height;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any help would be really much appreciated !

Comment: Do you make sure that character texels are mapped exactly to screen space pixels? Otherwise this result can be due to linear interpolation.

Comment: Well I'm not sure. I'm currently trying without any scaling, but the result doesn't look the same as the picture of the character. I've looked at the final MVP matrix that goes in the texture shader, and I don't see anything weird.

Comment: Do you think it could be due to the fact that the screen size is in Points and the textures size are in Pixels ?

Comment: No. My guess is that your texture lookups are not exactly in the center of the pixels. Since I don't know how you draw your texture it's impossible to tell. If you're rendering a quad, make sure that all corners map (after projection) exactly to screen pixels. If you're, for example, half a pixel off, then you get interpolated values from the texture.